# Can I avoid a possible hang by limiting the time a method is allowed to take?

Tags: vb.net, pdfsharp

I am using an external DLL (pdfsharp) to open (then manipulate) lots of PDF files.  I use:

```
Dim inputDocument = Pdf.IO.PdfReader.Open(PDFPath, IO.PdfDocumentOpenMode.ReadOnly)
```

Problem is - it seems to hang on certain, rare files. I don't seem to get any timeout - it just hangs for hours on this line.  We read thousands of files with this code, always on tiny files, so I was thinking that a quick workaround might be to somehow timeout if the this method takes more than a second or two.  But I don't see a simple way to do this.  I am hoping to avoid spinning up a worker thread.

Any thoughts on how I might limit this threads allowed execution time, or is there a better (but simple) way?

Comment: If we could send samples to the PdfSharp team, I am sure they could find what the problem is, however the data in the PDFs cannot be shared - and is created by another institution.  We keep a table of the 'Unparsable' PDFs - it has only happened 6 times out of many thousands - but there is nothing unusual looking about them...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up working around this problem by creating an AbortableBackgroundWorker.  I am not sure whose code this ended up being - but we found it online and sharing it here.  In the rare case where one of the PDF's hangs the PdfSharp Open() call, we abort the background worker.

```
  Public Class AbortableBackgroundWorker
    Inherits BackgroundWorker

    Private workerThread As Thread

    Protected Overrides Sub OnDoWork(e As DoWorkEventArgs)
        workerThread = Thread.CurrentThread
        Try
            MyBase.OnDoWork(e)
        Catch generatedExceptionName As ThreadAbortException
            e.Cancel = True
            'We must set Cancel property to true!
            'Prevents ThreadAbortException propagation
            Thread.ResetAbort()
        End Try
    End Sub


    Public Sub Abort()
        If workerThread IsNot Nothing Then
            workerThread.Abort()
            workerThread = Nothing
        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

The Open() call should not hang. Never. If you provide us with a file that causes Open() to hang, we can investigate this.

Does your program run on a server? Do you use a DEBUG build of PDFsharp? Maybe it's just a simple Debug.Assert() that is triggered, but noone can answer it. Using a RELEASE build would solve this.

Comment: I believe I am using a release version.  It is version 1.31.1789.0 (runtime version v2.0.50727).

Comment: Apparently hitting enter posts the comment.  I was using the assemblies download dll.  I just downloaded the latest project and built in Release.  Is there a spot to grab RELEASE assemblies that I can be sure?   It is version 1.31.1789.0 (runtime version v2.0.50727). Unfortunately, I cannot send one of the PDF's. I am not running on a server.

Comment: All I can confirm is it does hang, if the PDF file is not valid.

Comment: @Yuan If you provide a file that causes PDFsharp to hang then there is a chance we fix that issue. Some invalid files cause exceptions, some invalid files lead to endless loops, some invalid files can be read if the errors can be ignored.